# Increase the character limit for custom suggested edit rejections

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Today, while I was at work, somebody suggested [a bad edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14571025) to one of my posts. It wasn't *immediately obviously* bad, and so I took a minute to look at it. At the end of that minute, I wanted to write something like this:

> The linked answer is to a fundamentally different question to mine; my answer addresses how to avoid clients sending revalidation requests that will result in 304s and instead induce those clients to serve content from their caches without revalidation, while the linked answer addresses how to avoid clients storing content in their caches at all. These are different (almost opposite) objectives with different solutions.
>
> Additionally:
>
> - The sentence added doesn't make much sense in context. What does *"works"* mean here? I'm not sure, and expect most readers won't be either.
> - Even if it *were* a completely correct answer to this question, the linked answer is clearly suggesting a completely different course of action to mine; if it were correct, then mine must be mostly or wholly wrong. The right remedy in that situation is to downvote and comment to express dissent, not to add a [caveat in paragraph 19](http://www.badscience.net/2010/10/the-caveat-in-paragraph-number-19/) that contradicts everything said so far and torpedoes the central premise of the answer.

Of course, such a reason would be too long by close to 1000 characters. So, lacking the time to figure out how to express everything above within the tiny character limit available to me, I settled for this:

> This is nonsense; the linked question is asking something completely different.

The thing is, having to write the above makes me feel like a dick. It doesn't *quite* just say *"your edit is stupid and you are stupid; go away"*, but it's pretty close. And I was happy to write out a full explanation for this misguided editor of what they had done wrong, but *the site stopped me*; the unhelpfulness and near-rudeness of my rejection was imposed upon me by the character limit, rather than being the response I actually wanted to give.

I know that the majority of people reading this are going to think that the response I'd like to have given is far more effort than a suggested edit deserves. Perhaps so (though I can express my own thoughts much more rapidly than I can figure out things that I don't understand, and wrote out the message above in less time than some difficult reviews in unfamiliar subject areas have taken me). But on the odd occasion that somebody is willing to put in the effort, what harm does it do to let them type more advice? I feel like I came across as expressing contempt towards a well-meaning user here, and I'd rather that the site had given me the space to do something better and more respectful.

Comment: I think you can @-ping suggested editors, so you could have made (several) comments on your question (or created a chat room) to discuss.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom that's a legit approach, but I prefer not to have to make publicly-visible noise in order to give feedback to an editor. Comments on the answer really aren't the ideal place to discuss the edit.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Pretty sure it's only editors *after* approval.

Comment: @Nathan Well that's pretty silly. I'm much more likely to want to comment about a rejected edit than an approved one.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Well, it's implemented as part of the more general idea of allowing contact with anyone (2k or otherwise) who's actually edited the post. Adding suggestions to it wouldn't be a bad idea, but hasn't been done as far as I know.

Comment: It's a great idea, but I don't think many editors actually read the reject reasons. I've lost count of the times I've rejected edits that merely put `product names` in code markdown, or added a DO NOT USE tag, explaining exactly why I rejected... only to see the same editor happily make more of the same bad edits the next day.

Comment: I'm upvoting this, not because I think it's an especially useful feature or anyone will actually read these rejection reasons, but because every time I come across a textbox with an arbitrary character limit, it always pisses me off.

Comment: +1 for the "your edit is stupid and you are stupid; go away" even though we should all know better, it's pety and bad manners and not fit for a professional environment / environment full of professionals..