# Moderator's reply to my flag ends with an ellipsis; was there more to the message?

Tags: support, flags, character-limit

I raised a flag on [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805415/how-do-i-create-a-schema-for-a-typical-college-framework), requesting moderators to migrate [the question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/302005/how-do-i-create-a-schema-for-a-typical-college-framework) to [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Flag]

As you can see, the moderator who's migrated the question, has nicely replied to the flag (thanks a lot whoever that was :) ). Now, it looks as though I am unable to see the complete reply, but I don't know, those *...* might be how the moderator ended the reply. I just wanted to know if that is the complete reply, or am I missing some part of the reply?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Nope; they're not automatically shortened. It's far, far worse than that:

They have to be *manually* shortened, because the character limit for flag response messages is *ridiculously* short. The message you see there? That fills the *entire* character limit. I literally had no more space left to type even a single additional character.

If I'd had just a *tiny* bit more space, I would have said something like:

> …best of luck!

But I suspect even that would have been cryptic. It would have been better to be able to say something like:

> …I will go ahead and trust that you read their Help Center, are confident that it would be a good fit, and migrate it anyway, per your request.

I had hoped that the ellipsis would allow you to infer this detail, but I really had no other choice.

Comment: I couldn't find a feature request for increasing the character limit. Do moderators use some other channels for requesting features?

Comment: I mostly just scream really loudly into the sky, while clenching and shaking my fists. I find it to be equally, if not more, effective. No requests have been honored so far to increase the character limit on... anything, so I don't think anyone has even bothered to request this particular one. @Tadeusz

Comment: So you get big shovel, but trowel-size commenting space. Interesting trade-off.

Comment: Life would be boring if stuff would make sense.

Comment: @CodyGray didn’t they increase the charecter limit on tag names a while back?

Comment: plz rd help migrated neway kthxbye

Comment: Are moderators discouraged from sending a whole reply through email?

Comment: Yes, @AndrewMorton, that would be very strongly discouraged. I would never do so in response to a flag. Raising a flag on this site doesn't (in itself) give me permission to reveal your email address (which is PII), and certainly doesn't consent to me sending you email. Even if you said in the flag message that you wanted to receive a reply via email, I would probably have to decline that, too, since it's better that all of the content related to this site is kept *on this site*.

Comment: *"every time I come across a textbox with an arbitrary character limit, it always pisses me off"* - [Cody Gray, 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339463/increase-the-character-limit-for-custom-suggested-edit-rejections#comment420868_339463). Some things have changed in 5 years, but the arbitrary character limits have not, and it would seem that Cody's animus towards them has not either. And quite right - they are just pointlessly harmful. You could remove them or at least make them 20x larger and cause no harm at all while making the site better. But nobody will.

Comment: On @AndrewMorton's point about email - something that Bhargav did once was start a chat conversation with me about a flag I'd raised that was complicated to handle and where I'd missed an important nuance. It was helpful that he did so, I appreciated it, it let us figure out the right solution, and there was no reason for me to care about the privacy of that particular flag content so I didn't mind at all that it technically became public. Nonetheless, I can see how that's not something mods would generally want to do, because there is a presumption that all flags are private.

Comment: It really is unfortunate that mods don't have any non-problematic tool or tactic available to them to reply at length to a flag, but alas, that's the status quo.

Comment: I have, on multiple occasions, also started private chat rooms with people to discuss their flags in more detail. *Most* of the time, it's over the moderation of (or concerns about perceived moderation of) content here on Meta, which I take rather seriously, given how much I value and seek to protect the ability of the community to speak their mind freely here, including the expression of minority views. But I have also done this for flags on the main site. It's just that these main site flags don't usually require extended discussion with the flagger.

Comment: Using chat in this way was, in fact, first suggested to me many years ago when I asked, [How are we intended to respond to moderator flags that ask a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97150) Asking questions in flags is a major anti-pattern, so we strongly encourage people not to do it, but if it's absolutely necessary, chat is about the only recourse we have to actually answer those questions.

Comment: @CodyGray wait, do *private* chat rooms exist? I didn't realise they did (I checked before commenting above and am pretty sure I can't create one as a normal user - maybe they're a mod-only feature) and I don't *recall* seeing any indication that the room I was in previously was private.

Comment: Yes, they're a mod-only feature. Mods can mark any chat room private, which makes access to it mod-only. This is used for a "Private Trash" chat room, which room owners can use to move messages out of their rooms that should never be seen anymore (a hack around the frustrating limitation of chat that ROs cannot delete messages, only mods can). Mods also have a private mod-only chat room for coordinating mod efforts. In addition, mods can grant specific users read-only or read-write access to a private room. So, we create a new room for us and the other user, make it private, then grant access.

Answer (score 11):

As a supplementary answer:

The extremely small character limit on declined flag messages is a well-known and old problem, nothing you can do about it other than ask on Meta (which you did) and wait for the moderator who handled your flag to provide a detailed response (which they did) - this is, unfortunately, the best we have right now.

To put things into perspective, here is a small compilation of public complaints (both explicit and covert) made about the character limit (both direct or otherwise) not counting this post:

| Year | Post | Gist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | [Why did a moderator delete my answer which I moved from a different question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407759/why-did-a-moderator-delete-my-answer-which-i-moved-from-a-different-question/407763#407763) | If that flag is declined, you can always come to meta to ask for more feedback, where both the community and moderators can post longer form answers than what the decline message allows. |
| 2020 | [I would like a more detailed explanation for why my recent moderator flags were declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403932/i-would-like-a-more-detailed-explanation-for-why-my-recent-moderator-flags-were/403933#403933) | Even when we do decide to type out a custom message, we hit an extremely small character limit for these messages. |
| 2020 | [Add the ability to request the Review of a declined flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394348/add-the-ability-to-request-the-review-of-a-declined-flag/394350#394350) | Flag decline messages have strict limits in terms of the number of characters. |
| 2020 | [Exactly how much support is required for a feature request to meet the criteria for escalation as per the new procedure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346787/exactly-how-much-support-is-required-for-a-feature-request-to-meet-the-criteria/346792#346792) | this answer intentionally doesn't try to offer an explanation for the declined flag message. Perhaps other factors are at play, but there's a character limit for flag messages. |
| 2019 | [How is this question "not even close to being off-topic"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392447/how-is-this-question-not-even-close-to-being-off-topic/392467#392467) | If nothing else, there's a character limit placed on our responses, which I run into all the time under normal circumstances. |
| 2011 | [Length limit for the "other" field in the Decline Flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106665/length-limit-for-the-other-field-in-the-decline-flag-dialog) | Can the limit be increased to make the messages more meaningful? |

I failed to find any public feature requests (as moderators are users first and foremost and so [can and do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderator-tools+feature-request) [[MSE version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request%2Bmoderators?tab=active&pagesize=50)] make [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) posts) that would explicitly ask for increasing the limit, though. Maybe it is time to [create one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) — they are even honored from time to time.

Comment: Hmmm... "explicit" and "overt" kind of mean the same thing in this context. Typically, one says "both explicit and implicit" if one means both the limit is mentioned as the topic or the limit is mentioned in passing. Anyway, just caught my eye as an odd turn of phrase.

Comment: @HereticMonkey heh, thanks, typo'd - the meaning is "covert"

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

*If* they were shortened, you'd have some way to access the full message.